# My Mysql Cross Join database failed ... Who can help me?

Tags: mysql, sql

Below are two tables and a query that links them.

Uncles

```
Name    Age    
Eric    38
Kim     63
Rock    44
```

Aunts

```
Name    Age
Annie   24
Brenda  64
Emma    54
```

```
SELECT aunts.name AS aunt, uncles.name AS uncle 
    FROM aunts JOIN uncles
        ON aunts.age > uncles.age;
```

**1)    How many rows will this query return?**

**2)    How many rows will result if you cross join a table that has 10 rows with a table that has 60 rows?**

Comment: Is there any part of this homework question that is tripping you up that we can concentrate on helping with?

Comment: those are two separate questions.  and the first one is *not* about a cross join, since it does not include all combinations of every row from the two tables.  does that help you at all?

Answer (score 1):

In `join` two **tables**, one row of the first table is compared with all the rows of the second table.

*If the first table has **`n`** records and the second table has **`m`** records and all of them are true in the `join` condition, n * m records result.*

**1) How many rows will this query return?** **`Returns 5 records`**

**2) How many rows will result if you cross join a table that has 10 rows with a table that has 60 rows?** **`Depends on condition aunts.age> uncles.age; has it`**

Comment: Thanks for giving me the answer, this is the answer, I passed the practical test and in the end I have a little bit of difficulty ... Hi David